# Sublime Text 2 Activating Multi Select Mac

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to use multi select on a mac for sublime text 2, but as soon as I "find" several selections with command d, I am unsure of what to press to start writing to those selected fields. Everything I hit makes me edit what is in the find field, create cursors for all fields (alt+enter), or leave find / replace mode (escape).

I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to multi select in "find", select one of them with cursor, then just use `command d` to multi select next(also can skip the next by `command d -> command k`). then just type anything to edit them.

Comment: Awesome, I feel a bit foolish. Is there a way to activate it with the find window open or no?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `COMMAND + D`: select any occurrence, then use `COMMAND + CTRL + G` to multi-select all occurrences throughout the current file.